# Adding a character after a digit and dot in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to modify my a variable by adding `\` between any digit and the dot just before it,
So far I only managed to add the `\` after the first digit and the first dot.

My script:

```
branch="3.2.5"
firstbranch=$(echo $branch | sed -r 's/([0-9]+.)(.)/\1\\2/g') && echo $firstbranch
```

the output it generates:

```
3.\2.5
```

and the desired output:

```
3.\2.\5
```

Comment: Forward slash or back slash?

Comment: try `sed -E 's/([0-9])\./\1.\\/g' <<< "$branch"`

Comment: You wrote _adding \ between any digit and a dot_, but in your desired output you did put a \ between any dot and a digit, i.e. in the other order.

Comment: fixed , sorry for the mix up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\./&\\/g' <<< "$branch"
```

```
3.\2.\5
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you are ok with `awk`, could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in link https://ideone.com/T1suTg

```
echo "$branch" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=".";OFS=".\\"} {$1=$1} 1'
```

***Explanation:*** Printing shell variable `branch` value with `echo` and sending its output as standard input to `awk` command. In `awk` program in `BEGIN` block setting field separator as `.` and setting output field separator as `.\\` which is actually `.\` Then in main program re-setting 1st field to itself so that new value of output field separator get applies. `1` will print value of current line.

Answer (score 2):

Also, it is possible to use POSIX BRE expression with `sed` to insert `\` between a dot and a digit:

```
branch="3.2.5"
firstbranch=$(echo $branch | sed 's/\(\.\)\([[:digit:]]\)/\1\\\2/g') && echo $firstbranch
```

Result: `3.\2.\5`

See [online proof](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P6koMS85w1bJWM9Iz1SJKy2zqLgEKqaikZqcka@gAuEq1CgUp6YoqBfrx2jE6MVoxmhER1ulZKZnlljFxsZo6scYxsTEGOmnq2sqqKkpQHQimfb/PwA).

**Regex Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [[:digit:]]              any character of: digits (like \d)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                        end of \2
```

Answer (score 1):

Varible expansion

```
branch="3.2.5"
echo ${branch//./.\\}
3.\2.\5
```

Comment: the simple and short solution among all proposed